# codeigniter: out of memory

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp, force-download

[this is the print screen of my error, please click..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4WTG.jpg)

I'm using codeigniter here,
this is my controller...

```
class Copy extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    redirect('home');
    ini_set("memory_limit", "4096M");
}

public function getFile($file = '')
{
    $this->load->model('home_model');
    $files = $this->home_model->getFile($file);
    $this->load->library('zip');
    $this->load->helper('download');

    if($files !== FALSE)
    {
        foreach ($files->result() as $row)
        {

            $data = file_get_contents(base_url().$row->File_Path); // Read the file's contents

            $name = substr($row->File_Path, 26);
            $name2 = str_replace("_", " ", $name);

            force_download($name2, $data);
        }
    }

}
```

}

I'm using codeigniter helper **DOWNLOAD**, to download file in the server...

I already, update **memory_limit** in **php.ini 2048M TO 4096M**, it seems nothings happen, and I tried to put **ini_set('memory_limit','4096M');** in my code, and it didn't work also...

can someone tell me how to fix this... THANK YOU

Comment: u need to clear your variable

Comment: what variable ? thanks for the reply...

Comment: Post your `home_model` `getFile()` method too. If CI v3+ is used, your `copy.php` should be `Copy.php`.

Comment: suggest that you first try to get it working with a much smaller file.